# How to highlight SQL syntax of Room Dao in Android Studio

Tags: android, sql, syntax-highlighting, android-studio-3.0, android-room

With new [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html), How to highlight SQL Syntax in `Dao` Interfaces?

For example `@Query(SELECT * FROM user)` is it possible to highlight the words `SELECT, FROM` with a different color and text format than the word `user`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer from [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7g9246/dont_forget_to_inject_android_room_sql_language/)

[image]

Comment: How do you activate that menu?

Comment: Alt+Enter on Linux or Windows

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but if you are using `kotlin-dsl (gradle ktx)` and implement dependencies with `buildSrc` on `build.gradle` file like this (object reference):

[image]
[image]

```
implementation(Dependencies.AndroidX.room)
implementation(Dependencies.AndroidX.roomKtx)
kapt(Dependencies.AndroidX.roomCompiler)
implementation(Dependencies.AndroidX.roomPaging)
```

That causes to not indexing (highlight or autocomplete) `Android Room SQL` Scripts, so when I tried to implement with directly using `String` like this:

[image]

```
val roomVersion = "2.4.2"
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-common:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$roomVersion")
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
```

that **worked** for me.

### Also I tried:

1. Changing the Java JDK version `11.0.11` to `11.0.15.1`
2. Invalidate Caches/Restart

### Aditionally

`build.gradle.kts (project)`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(BuildProject.GradlePlugins.androidNavigation)
        classpath(BuildProject.GradlePlugins.hilt)
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.2.1" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.7.10" apply false
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

`build.gradle.kts (module)`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

android {
    compileSdk = BuildApplication.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = BuildApplication.applicationId
        minSdk = BuildApplication.minSdk
        targetSdk = BuildApplication.targetSdk
        versionCode = BuildApplication.versionCode
        versionName = BuildApplication.versionName
        testInstrumentationRunner = BuildApplication.androidTestInstrumentation
        multiDexEnabled = true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                argument("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            }
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            multiDexEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()

    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    val roomVersion = "2.4.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-common:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$roomVersion")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    ...
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```