# Android Studio DAO Syntax Highlighting, DB Inspector and Language Injection

Tags: android-studio, android-room, syntax-highlighting

Since my last build upgrade, the syntax highlighting in my DAOs is not working anymore.
[image]

My expectation (and experience) is, that there is syntax highlighting in the queries and once the database inspector is running, there is also a button on the left side, which executes the SQL statement on the running database.
I don't know, why this happened. The only thing I did, was run recommended upgrades for my build gradles. Also, reverting these changes did not improve the situation.

At least in regards to syntax highlighting I found a solution:
[image]

However, that still does not resolve the problem of "Quick running" the sql statement in the database inspector.

Also to note here, I tried already this: [How to highlight SQL syntax of Room Dao in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711005/how-to-highlight-sql-syntax-of-room-dao-in-android-studio), which did not work. In my case, there is no listing for "Android Room SQL", but only "Room SQL".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Auto highlighting still doesn't work with:

*Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023*

and

*room: 2.5.0*

in kotlin @Dao class.

So, as said [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234612964#comment6), you should:

1. Go to Settings > Editor > Language Injections
2. Add a new injection of type "Generic Kotlin"
3. Choose "RoomSQL" as the ID for the injection.
4. Add the following for the "Places Patterns":

   + kotlinParameter().ofFunction(0, kotlinFunction().withName("Query").definedInClass("androidx.room.Query"))

   + kotlinParameter().ofFunction(0, kotlinFunction().withName("DatabaseView").definedInClass("androidx.room.DatabaseView"))

And injection works fine!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have asked same question at issuetracker.google.com: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234612964

An intermediate solution is here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234612964#comment6

Please check that link out, there is a work-around there which works with '2.5.0-alpha03' at least. Haven't tested it with '2.5.0-alpha02'.

There will be a fix for it in Android Studio soon (september/october 2022)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use alpha version of room in gradle. Use stable version only.
I was using alpha version of room:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.5.0-alpha02'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.5.0-alpha02'
```

When I migrated to stable version it resolved the issue.

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.3'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.4.3'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.3'
```