# autocomplete for room query stopped working?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

After opening my room dao I noticed that the autocomplete for `Query` annotation does not work at all. Not only that, but it also does not check any SQL queries I try to enter for errors and spelling mistakes:

[image: Proof]

( I purposefully used "FRR" instead of "FROM" to show that the error correction does not work )

I've already tried to invalidate caches and restarting android studio, but that changed nothing.
Any ideas?

(also, just for the sake of it: The autocomplete works for standard kotlin code, just not inside that query string)

Comment: I have to switch from Room version 2.5.2 to 2.4.3 to make it work. It is for you to decide if you wan to downgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile, then the error will be detected and will be available in the build log.

e.g.

```
E:\AndroidStudioApps\SO72784799KotlinRoomJSON11\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\a\a\so72784799kotlinroomjson1_1\AllDao.java:35: error: extraneous input 'FRR' expecting {<EOF>, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}
    public abstract java.util.List<a.a.so72784799kotlinroomjson1_1.AddedPhotoEntity> getSomething();
```

- The above used an existing project with a function in an @Dao annotated interface based upon

:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FRR AddedPhotoEntity")
fun getSomething(): List<AddedPhotoEntity>
```

Although at one time SQL was checked/auto completed for Room annotations, this hasn't been the case for some time now. Frequently compiling and checking the build log, is (IMHO) a must.

Comment: SELECT * FRR ?, or SELECT * FROM ?, Sorry if i misunderstood

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki I purposefully used "FRR" instead of "FROM" to show that the error correction does not work

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73835301/8623184

You can either downgrade to stable room version, or use fix from here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234612964#comment6

Answer (score 0):

step 1: Check your gradel dependencies working correctly
step 2: clean and rebuild your project.